# How to calculate Cache hit ratio from 2-way set associate cache

Tags: caching

On my assignment we have 2 questions: we have a 2-way set associative cache. The cache has four sets in total. Main memory consists of 4K blocks of 8 words each and word addressing is used.
Part a) ask to demonstrate the address format, which I've solved to be word = 3 bit set =2 bit and field = 7 bit. The problem im having is in part b):
Compute the hit ratio for a program that loops 3 times from location 8 to location 51. In other words, think of this as an assembly language program that runs from the opcode at location 8 to the opcode at location 51m then loops back to location 8. It does three such iterations in total.

Now to my understanding after the research I've done there's a standard normally some sort of speed or hit rate that is given? I was wondering how do i calculate the hit ratio if i don't know a miss rate, a miss penalty a cache speed or anything?

Answer (score 1):

I think we're in the same class lol I have the exact same question on assignment due tonight.. Anyway I did some research and found this answer to a similar question on chegg:

```
a. Given that memory contains 2K blocks of eight words.
2K can be distributed as 2K * 23 = 211* 23 = 214 so we have 14-bit addresses with 9 bits
in the tag field, 2 bits in the set field and 3 in the word field

b. First iteration of the loop:
    → Address 8 is a miss, then entire block brought into Set 1.9-15 are then hits.
    → 16 is a miss, entire block brought into Set 2, 17-23 are hits.
    → 24 is a miss, entire block brought into Set 3, 25-31 are hits.
    → 32 is a miss, entire block brought into Set 0, 33-39 are then hits.
    → 40 is a miss, entire block brought into Set 1 41-47 are hits.
    → 48 is a miss, entire block brought into Set 2, 49-51 are hits.

    For the first iteration of the loop, we have 6 misses, and 5*7 + 3 hits, or 38 hits.
    On the remaining iterations, we have 5*8+4 hits, or 44 hits each,for 88 more hits.
    Therefore, we have 6 misses and 126 hits, for a hit ratio of 126/132, or 95.45%.
```

Hope this helps, good luck!

Comment: By the way, I didn't get the same answer as you did for part a. I got 10 bit tag field, 2 bit set field, 3 bit word field.